# GLSL Layout works strange

Tags: opengl, glsl

There are 2 layouts in my vertex shader

```
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
```

I set them by func glVertexAttrib3f();

```
glVertexAttrib3f(1, 0, 1, 0); // color

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); // vertexes
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 0, 0, 0);
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 1, 0, 0);
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 1, 1, 0);
glEnd();
```

In this situation, everything is ok, I have my green triangle in a window. But if I swap my aPos layout and aColor (set 1 to aPos and 0 to aColor)

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aPos;
```

and also dont forgot to swap them in my cpp file

```
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 0, 1, 0); // color

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); // vertexes
glVertexAttrib3f(1, 0, 0, 0);
glVertexAttrib3f(1, 1, 0, 0);
glVertexAttrib3f(1, 1, 1, 0);
glEnd();
```

nothing dont work and my window is empty (it must draw green triangle)
Why it works so?

Comment: [This is answerable](https://community.khronos.org/t/glvertexattrib-problem/59494) from the information provided - voting to reopen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `glVertexAttrib` with an index of `0` is a special kind of command: It will result in a vertex being *emitted* using all the vertex attributes previously set.

See OpenGL 2.0 specification (where `glVertexAttrib` was introduced) section 2.7. "Vertex Specification":

> Setting generic vertex **attribute zero specifies a vertex**; the four vertex coordinates are taken from the values of attribute zero. A Vertex2, Vertex3, or Vertex4
> command is completely equivalent to the corresponding VertexAttrib* command
> with an index of zero. Setting any other generic vertex attribute updates the current
> values of the attribute. There are no current values for vertex attribute zero

When you do:

```
glVertexAttrib3f(1, 0, 1, 0); // color
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 0, 0, 0);
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 1, 0, 0);
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 1, 1, 0);
```

then essentially you emit three vertices with their `index=1` attribute having the value `(0, 1, 0)`.

On the other hand, when you do:

```
glVertexAttrib3f(0, 0, 1, 0); // color
glVertexAttrib3f(1, 0, 0, 0);
glVertexAttrib3f(1, 1, 0, 0);
glVertexAttrib3f(1, 1, 1, 0);
```

then what happens is that you first emit *one* vertex with all its attributes having their default/zero values and then set the value of the vertex attribute with `index=1` to effectively `(1, 1, 0)` (the last call). That will only be really used whenever you *emit* another vertex by calling `glVertexAttrib3f(0, ...)`.

So, the bottom line is: The vertex attribute with index `0` has a special meaning in that it will also *emit* a vertex. So a call with `glVertexAttrib3f(0, ...)` should *always* be the *last* call per vertex after all the other attributes *for that* vertex have been set.